# How can I get a Washington driver's license within 30 days of my move to Washington?

Tags: usa, residency, driving-license

https://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/moving.html states:

> By law, you have 30 days after you move to Washington (WA) to get your WA driver license. You will also need your WA driver license before you can register any vehicles here.

However, to be able to obtain a Washington's driver's license, I have to provide one or two proofs of residency. My issue is that I don't see how I can collect them within 30 days, as after moving to Washington state, I'm staying a few weeks in a short-term accommodation (Airbnb) in Washington state before moving into my long-term rent.

http://www.dmv-seattle.org/wa-washington/drivers-license/id-proof.html#residence gives the list of accepted proofs of residency:

**Option 1:** Show us [1 document from this list](http://www.dmv-seattle.org/wa-washington/drivers-license/id-proof.html#onedoc).

- Parental address. If you are under 18 and your parent or guardian shows proof of your identity and relationship, you may use their Washington residential address. Not possible, I'm over 18.
- Certificate of Eligibility for Exchange Visitor (J-1) Form DS2019. I don't have such a certificate.
- Valid concealed weapons permit issued by a county in Washington. I don't have such a permit.
- Homeowner’s insurance policy or invoice showing the address of the insured property or residence. I don't own a place.
- Home utility bill (such as gas, electricity, water, garbage, landline telephone, or cable) or hook-up work order dated within the past 60 days. You must be the only person named on the bill or work order. I'm subletting, I'm not paying utilities.
- Mortgage documents. I haven't purchased a place.
- Property tax bill or statement dated within the past 12 months. I haven't purchased a place.
- Your name and address in a current phone book made by a telephone book publisher. I don't have a landline phone.
- Moorage bill or contract showing you live on a boat in a marina. I don't own a boat.
- Federal or state government agency-issued check. I don't have such checks.
- Tribal ID that contains your current residential address. I'm not part of a tribe.
- A filed property deed or title for your current residence. I don't own a place.

**Option 2:** Show us [2 documents from this list](http://www.dmv-seattle.org/wa-washington/drivers-license/id-proof.html#twodoc).

- Auto insurance policy (not the proof of insurance card). Maybe? How fast does it take? Can I use the Airbnb address for that?
- Business license from Washington State or a Washington city. I don't own a business.
- Business mail dated within the past 60 days. Mail must include your first and last name, and must be from state or federal revenue departments, the Social Security Administration, the U.S. Treasury, or the IRS. It cannot be addressed “in care of,” “for,” or “parent of.” I don't have such mail.
- Current Washington State voter card. I am not a US citizen and subsequently can't vote.
- Home utility bill (such as gas, electricity, water, garbage, landline telephone, or cable) or hook-up work order dated within the past 60 days. Two or more unrelated people may be named on the bill or work order. I don't have any since my Airbnb pay for everything.
- Medical record paid by insurance or a medical bill dated within the past 60 days. I could do that.
- DSHS medical coupon dated within the past 60 days. I don't have such coupons.
- Pay stub dated within the past 60 days that contains your name, your current residence address, your employer’s name, and your employer’ phone number or address. My next pay stub may not come in time.
- Professional license (nurse, physician, engineer, etc.) issued by Washington State. I don't have any professional license.
- Selective service card showing a Washington State address. I don't have any selective service card.
- Professionally-filed tax return or filed copy sent to you by the IRS for the most recent tax filing year. I won't receive it in time,
- Transcript or report card for the current school year from an educational institution in Washington State. I don't attend school.
- W-2 form for the previous year. I wasn't in Washington last year.
- Washington Agency Earnings and Deductions Statement. I don't have it.

I could patronize a medical provider to try to get a medical bill within 30 days. But I need a second proof. Which other acceptable proof of residency can I get within 30 days?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135398/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-how-can-i-get-a-washington-drivers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several of the items can probably be obtained within 30 days of the time you move out of the airbnb. If asked why you didn't get a new license within 30 days of moving into the airbnb, you could say you were evaluating whether your move to Washington was a good idea, and you weren't sure if you would stay.

For the medical record, it might not be necessary to have any new medical care. You might be able to change your address with your current medical care provider and then ask them to mail a copy of one of your existing records, such as the record of your COVID-19 vaccination. If the date the record was printed out is contained within the mail you receive, that may be sufficient.